# Can't start GAE project in Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I install the Google Plugin, the GAE SDK, and the GWT SDK per instructions.

I created a simple project, during which I found I had to manually point the Google Plugin to the GAE and GWT SDK directories (there were some previous directories, perhaps from a past installation, that no-longer existed).  I told it to generate the example code (the default functionality).

So then to test the example code I right click on the project, and go to Run As -> Web Application.

In the Console I see this:

```
2011-03-17 22:31:20.809 java[86443:a07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2011-03-17 22:31:20.813 java[86443:a07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed /Users/ian/workspace/CustLTV/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed /Users/ian/workspace/CustLTV/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
jetty-6.1.x
Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

It then seems to quit immediately (the red box that indicates it is running goes grey).

There is also a "Development Mode" tab which lists the following URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/CustLTV.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

When I click on that I'm taken to that URL, but I get "Connection refused", nothing is listening on that port.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The logs are normal. Edit the `log4j.properties`, set the log level to DEBUG and see what happends. Check `netstat -an`, make sure nothing else is listening to 8888.

Comment: Nothing running on 8888, I've updated the question to include the output on log level FINEST (it seems that it uses java.util.logging, not log4j).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Shengta's reply here http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712
Worked for me

Comment: Worked for me too.  Specifically, comment 39 at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712#c39 solved the problem.  (Downgrade to Java Update 3.)